# installing NPM crawler

Tags: node.js, npm, web-crawler

I am trying to install NPM crawler on windows using command

```
npm install crawler
```

It is failing to install with following debug info

```
5874 error Error: ENOENT, lstat 'E:\Project\test\node_modules\crawler\node_modules\request\node_modules\hawk\node_modules\sntp\node_modules\hoek\images\hoek.png'
5875 error If you need help, you may report this log at:
5875 error     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
5875 error or email it to:
5875 error     <npm-@googlegroups.com>
5876 error System Windows_NT 6.1.7600
5877 error command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "crawler"
5878 error cwd E:\Project\test
5879 error node -v v0.10.17
5880 error npm -v 1.3.8
5881 error path E:\Project\test\node_modules\crawler\node_modules\request\node_modules\hawk\node_modules\sntp\node_modules\hoek\images\hoek.png
5882 error fstream_path E:\Project\test\node_modules\crawler\node_modules\request\node_modules\hawk\node_modules\sntp\node_modules\hoek\images\hoek.png
5883 error fstream_type File
5884 error fstream_class FileWriter
5885 error code ENOENT
5886 error errno 34
5887 error fstream_stack C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\fstream\lib\writer.js:284:26
5887 error fstream_stack Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)
5888 verbose exit [ 34, true ]
```

Comment: Did you ever get round this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a issue with npm website and it was not responding well. Same command worked next day.